# Recommended GPU for watching movies on 4k or 1440p quad monitor setup

Tags: graphics-cards, multiple-monitors, displays

My goal is to obtain a productivity setup with quad (four) monitor setup that can handle 3 1440p monitors, and 1 4k monitor for movies (no gaming on that specific monitor). Would 1070ti be enough or do I need another better GPU?

Also, I understand for good quality I will use display port and HDMI 2.0 or higher port. Any CPU, Ram size recommendations?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hw Recs! It would help us recommend the best GPU if you were to be as **specific as possible** (e.g. Price, etc.). You've also asked for RAM, CPU recommendations. It would be best to ask all 3 as a single recommendation, or each on an individual basis.

Comment: @BennettYeo not worried about the price at the moment just curious about which GPU would be recommended.

Comment: @JosephBourne You mentioned gaming, just not on the 4K. What games would you like play and at what settings? What about other graphic intensive programs? The more you tell us about your graphics card and what you plan on doing with it, the better our recommendations are going to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically answering for Nvidia GPUs:

A GTX 1070ti will have no problem at all running 3 2560x1440 monitors and 1 4K for video and desktop computing as long as you are using the correct display outputs and monitors that support HDMI 2.0, DVI-D, or Displayport.

You should theoretically be able to run 4 4K screens off of any 10XX, or 20XX series card, or a higher end 9XX series as these nvidia architectures all support 4 displays.

For the rest of the hardware:

CPU and RAM usage typically goes up as you have more applications open to fill the 4 screens, this will vary greatly depending on what those applications are though. If you update your question with specifically what applications you are using, then I can give a recommendation suited to your workload. Otherwise, any quad core CPU from the recent AMD or Intel series and at least 8GB of RAM will likely be sufficient.

Edit:
One more thing that I should mention is regarding 4K video playback. It is possible that some applications or browsers could ignore the video decoding features of your GPU and work the CPU very hard to decode the 4K video. In those cases it's best to have as fast of a CPU as possible. This is likely only going to show up with outdated applications or drivers.

Comment: So basically an intel i9 processor would suffice for encoding and decoding the 4k video?

Comment: @JosephBourne, Even an i5 should handle CPU-based 4K playback if that's all you're doing; The edit was more about bringing attention to the fact that some video players or web browsers will make your CPU do the work instead of the GPU when playing 4K video. If the CPU is busy doing *other* things too, then you would want a faster CPU to handle all of that at the same time.